# How do I pass variables to new children? [flash AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, class, instance-variables, addchild

The code illustrates the problem pretty well, I've cut everything unrelated  out.

**Create 2-4 kinsmen when the game starts**

```
function createInitialKinsmen()
{
    for (var k:int = 1; k < 3 + Math.round(Math.random() * 2; k++)
    {
        if (k == 1)
        {
            createKinsmen(0);
            trace ("player");
        }
        else
        {
            createKinsmen(1);
            trace ("starting kinsmen");
        }
    }
}
```

**Kinsmen creation function**

```
function createKinsmen(arrivalTypeVar:int)
{
    var newKinsmen = new kinsmen;
    listPanel.kinsmenDivider.addChild(newKinsmen);
    totalKinsmen++;
    totalKinsmenAlive++;
    newKinsmen.name = "kinsmen" + totalKinsmen;
    newKinsmen.arrivalType = arrivalTypeVar;
}
```

**Kinsmen class**

```
public class kinsmen extends MovieClip
{
    var arrivalType:int;
    function kinsmen()
    {
        trace(this.name);
        if (this.arrivalType = 0)
        {
            trace("player");
        }
        if (this.arrivalType = 1)
        {
            trace("starting kinsmen");
        }
    }
}
```

The output should say:

```
kinsmen1
player
player
kinsmen2
starting kinsmen
starting kinsmen
kinsmen3
starting kinsmen
starting kinsmen
kinsmen4
starting kinsmen
starting kinsmen
```

But instead says:

```
kinsmen1
player
player
kinsmen2
player
starting kinsmen
kinsmen3
player
starting kinsmen
kinsmen4
player
starting kinsmen
```

Which means that the *arrivalType* variable isn't being passed on. It seems to be hard-coded variables can be passed though thus at the moment I have a square with alpha 0 inside the kinsmen movieclip and it's x position determines the value of *arrivalType* in the constructor but this surely can't be good practice, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: try changing `=` to `==` in your conditions

Comment: @www0z0k good catch, that will be a problem... I still think he needs to pass args to his constructors. His constructor logic executes and then afterwards he sets the variables that said logic depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to modify your constructor function for the `kinsmen` class to accept a parameter for the `arrivalType` and the `name`.

What you're currently doing is constructing a new `kinsmen` object and afterwards setting the `arrivalType`  and the `name` on that object. So when the constructor code runs, the `arrivalType` is the default value of an `int` which is 0.

Modify your constructor function like this in the `kinsmen` class:

```
function kinsmen(arrivalType:int, name:String)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.arrivalType = arrivalType;
    if (this.arrivalType == 0)
    {
        trace("player");
    }
    if (this.arrivalType == 1)
    {
        trace("starting kinsmen");
    }
}
```

And modify your `createKinsmen()` function so that it passes in a value for the `arrivalType`  to the constructor method, instead of setting the `arrivalType` and `name` after the object is created:

```
function createKinsmen(arrivalTypeVar:int)
{
    totalKinsmen++;
    totalKinsmenAlive++;
    var newKinsmen = new kinsmen(arrivalTypeVar, "kinsmen" + totalKinsmen);
    listPanel.kinsmenDivider.addChild(newKinsmen);
}
```

Comment: @Ashton glad it worked, be sure to make the change that www0z0k suggested (in the comments for your question). I'll edit my answer to include them (changing the = to ==).